# How to redirect to a route on ngOnit?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to redirect to a route when user directly paste the url.

I want to direct the user to /en/sell page on hitting the url

**`http://localhost:3000/en/sell/confirmation`**

here is my code,

```
  ngOnInit() { 
    this.storedListing = this.sellerFlow.getSellerFlowObject(); 
    if (this.storedListing === null) {
      this.router.navigate(['./']);
    }
  }
```

i can see this.router getting executed but the application does not have any change. what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `../` if you want to go from `/en/sell/confirmation` to `/en/sell/`:

```
this.router.navigate(['../']);
```

See the [documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#navigate-to-crisis-detail-with-a-relative-url).

Comment: Can you try `this.router.navigate(['/en/sell']);`

Answer (score 0):

You could instead redirect from your routing:

```
{
    path: 'en/sell/confirmation',
    redirectTo: 'en/sell',
    pathMatch: 'full'
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

export class AddDisplay {
  constructor(private router: Router){}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.router.navigate(['./SomewhereElse']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the `relativeTo` param, as below:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) { }

ngOnInit() { 
  this.storedListing = this.sellerFlow.getSellerFlowObject(); 
  if (this.storedListing === null) {
    this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }
}
```